# Cloudinary in React/Redux "blocked by CORS policy". Request header field authorization

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, cloudinary

I have problems with CORS on my localhost:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/*******/image/upload' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I work with react/redux. Below is my redux action for adding/changing profile. This code worked when I worked with http://localhost, but doesn't work with **https**. I wrote cors middleware in my server.js. But it doesn't help. What can I do with it?

```
export const addProfile = profile => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", profile.avatar);
  formData.append("api_key", "********");
  formData.append("upload_preset", "********");
  formData.append("skipAuthorization", true);

  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/********/image/upload',
      formData,
      { headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" } })
      .then(res => {
        const image = res.data.secure_url;
        profile.avatar = image;
        axios
          .post("/api/profile", profile)
          .then(res => {
            console.log("res", res.data);
          })
          .catch(err =>
            console.log("err", err.response.data);
          );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("cloundinary err =>", err))
  }
};
```

Comment: Any chance that you have set an Axios global default, such as an authorization header or `withCredentials = true`, somewhere ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51793283))? Asking because those are incompatible with the unsigned upload option. Also, you probably want `file` in your POST body, not `image`, based on [Cloudinary docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api).

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Looks like cloudinary doesn't allow to load file over https from client. Used server load instead

Answer (score -1):

The CORS problem is with the domain you are trying to access: https://api.cloudinary.com

They/You need to add your domain to the api response headers - or wildcard access if you need to access it from localhost. When enabled, you should be able to see the CORS headers in the api response.

See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing